# Convert float to string in Apache beam pipeline reading from Big Query

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

How do I convert type float to string in an apache beam pipeline reading from Big Query?

I am writing a piece of code to read from a column called **Expected** from a BigQuery table in GCP, which then looks for a regex in a string. However, it appears I run into a TypeERROR in my pipeline. It appears I have some fields of type float (i.e. 'NaN' values):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bla.py", line 147, in <module>
    | beam.Map(print))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 583, in __exit__
    self.result.wait_until_finish()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1665, in wait_until_finish
    self)
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1374, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/util.py", line 1082, in _process
    m = regex.match(element)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 54, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 359, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 221, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 719, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1241, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1306, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1401, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 221, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 719, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1241, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1306, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1401, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 221, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 719, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1241, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1306, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1401, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 221, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 719, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1241, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1321, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 446, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1239, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1374, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/util.py", line 1082, in _process
    m = regex.match(element)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object [while running 'Parse plants/FlatMap(_process)']
```

The code I have so far:

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery

table_spec = bigquery.TableReference(
    projectId='fill_in',
    datasetId='fill_in',
    tableId='fill_in')

options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='fill_in',
    job_name='fill_in',
    temp_location='gs://fill_in',
    region='us-central1')

# regex looks for expressions that are a sequence of numbers followed by a sequence of letters
regex = r'^\d+\s\w+?$'
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
  plants_matches = (
      pipeline
      | 'ReadTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=table_spec)
      | beam.Map(lambda elem: elem['Expected'])
      | 'Parse plants' >> beam.Regex.matches(regex)
      | beam.Map(print))
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Using `| 'To string' >> beam.ToString.Element()`  as one of the pipeline options, as follows:

```
regex = r'^\d+\s\w+?$'
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
  plants_matches = (
      pipeline
      | 'ReadTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=table_spec)
      | beam.Map(lambda elem: elem['Expected_Contract_Length'])
      | 'To string' >> beam.ToString.Element()
      | 'Parse plants' >> beam.Regex.matches(regex)
      | beam.Map(print))
```